# Forgot Login Password

Tags: wordplay

I'm always forgetting my login password.
When I try to login computer says your password is incorrect

So I did something so I will never forget my password

What I did?

This is my first Puzzling at Stackexchange

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have set your Password to :

> "Incorrect"

Comment: I think my puzzle is old :/

Comment: Yeah i know this was from  #Facebook, #Twitter, #Instragram.

Comment: Actually it should be lowercase "incorrect" ;)

Comment: Just use "12345".  That's the combination I use on my luggage.